# rabbitmq ldap not letting me use login as shortname

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to get rabbitmq ldap to work for me.

If I set user_dn_lookup_attribute to sAMAccountName, and dn_lookup_base to DC=COMPANY,DC=com, then user_dn_pattern, ${username}@COMPANY.COM, does not work for me.  In that, when my login for example is joesmo, ldap only knows joesmo@usa.company.com, not joesmo@company.com.  On the other hand, it does know joe.smo@company.com.  I want users to log in with the shortname, joesmo, not joe.smo.  Any ideas on how to address this?

I do not know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with RabbitMQ and LDAP authentication, however should your dn_lookup_base not be "DC=usa,DC=company,DC=com" to correctly resolve joesmo?

Perhaps the user_dn_pattern might also need to be "${username}@USA.COMPANY.COM".

Comment: No, I want users around the world to use it.  So DC=europe,DC=company,DC=com for example would exist too.  So use josmo@usa.company.com and sallyvalley@europe.company.com should be able to login.